# Percentile of array (in CUDA ) without sort?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, percentile

I have a 2560x2048 array of float values that I need the 25% and the 75% percentile values. (5,242,880) as a 1D vector. My first thought was to use a bitonic sort and fetch the value at 25% and 75%. But the Bitonic sort I have is for power of 2 arrays, and I don't want to go to a larger array with dummies.

This got me thinking that perhaps someone has a way of getting percentile without the overhead of a full sort?

Comment: The difference between a well-written sort code and an average sort code can be quite substantial in terms of performance.  Struggling with a less-than-optimal selection algorithm that hasn't had the best ninja efforts applied to it might be a less performant choice than simply going with the fastest available sort.  Sort in theory takes more work, but it's had quite a bit of effort put into it (e.g. [cub](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/index.html))  In any event, I think what you're asking for is a selection algorithm, such as [this one](http://code.google.com/p/ggks/).

Comment: Yea, what I am looking for is iqr, interquartile range, will the select algorithm be faster and simpler to code up?

Comment: Forget about sorting and cuda, but building histogram would be more easy understanding for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tae-Sung Shin is correct. Percentile from Histogram is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I know you're asking about non-sorting methods, but [Thrust](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html) does offer a sorting function.  I haven't tried it, but if it's anything like cuFFT, I'd expect it to be highly optimized.

You can also sort using [CUB](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/index.html) which apparently is faster than Thrust, according to [this link](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_radix_sort.html).

Another option would be finding percentiles from a histogram, though that might not be what you want for floating point values, unless you have a good way of partitioning the expected values into a series of bins.